# align the <div> to the right most column while scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the `<div>` with class `col-md-6` to be always positioned in the right end of the row even while scrolling horizontally.[Here](http://www.bootply.com/eIKwKHp5DS) is an illustration.

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="div1" class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
 <div id="div2" class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="test">LARGER DIV
</div>
```

When we scroll horizontally i want `div2` to remain in the last 6 columns of the window Which is not happening.The div itself is going out of the view.

Can you please specify or give some references to achieve this?I'm using Bootstrap-v3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the second div to absolute position, and make it keeps the right always at the border of the screen using some jQuery.

CSS:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    background: #F2FAFF;
    border: 0px solid #B1D8ED;
    display:inline-block;
}
.test{
    width:2000px;
    background: #F2F79F;
    border: 0px solid #B1D8ED;
}
#fixed{
    position:absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div id="fixed" class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    LARGER DIV
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#fixed').css('right', $(this).scrollLeft() * -1);
});
```

Example:

http://www.bootply.com/yeKqMVA91r

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap the larger div in a scrollable element like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow:scroll;">
        <div class="test">LARGER DIV</div>
    </div>
</div>
```